# how to unmarshal json and fill into structures in golang

Tags: arrays, json, go, data-structures

How to unmarshal the json and fill into structures. Like i'm having salesorder and salesorderdetails structures. In json i will have 1 record for salesorder and multiple items for salesorderdetails structure.

Here is the go code i have tried with single item and for multiple items, but working only for single record for salesorderdetails structure.

**Gocode:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Order struct {
    SalesId             string `json:"sales_id"`
    Customer string `json:"customer_name"`
    TotalPrice   string `json:"totalprice"`
}
type OrderDetails struct {
    DetailId             string `json:"detail_id"`
    SalesId             string `json:"sales_id"`
    ItemName string `json:"item_name"`
    Qty   string `json:"qty"`
    Price   string `json:"price"`
}
type Temp struct {

    Salesorder Order  `json:"Salesorder"`
    Salesorderdetails OrderDetails  `json:"OrderDetails"`
}

func main() {
    jsonByteArray := []byte(`[{"Salesorder":{"sales_id":"SOO1","customer_name":"CUST1","totalprice":"200"}, "OrderDetails":{"detailid":"1","sales_id":"SOO1","item_name":"ITEM1","qty":"2","price":"100"}}]`)

   //if i use above json it is working and if i use below json its not working
//jsonByteArray := []byte(`[{"Salesorder":{"sales_id":"SOO1","customer_name":"CUST1","totalprice":"200"}, "OrderDetails":{"detailid":"1","sales_id":"SOO1","item_name":"ITEM1","qty":"2","price":"100"},{"detailid":"2","sales_id":"SOO2","item_name":"ITEM2","qty":"3","price":"200"}}]`)

    var temp []Temp
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &temp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", temp)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n ", temp[0].Salesorder.SalesId)
}
```

**Error while using multiple items:**

```
panic: invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string
```

**Output while using single item with success:**

```
[{Salesorder:{SalesId:SOO1 Customer:CUST1 TotalPrice:200} Salesorderdetails:{SalesId:SOO1 ItemName:ITEM1 Qty:2 Price:100}}]
SOO1
```

**Fiddle:** updated with key in salesorderdetails

https://play.golang.org/p/klIAoNi18r

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect. Second part of OrderDetails is a value without key, and is not a part of the array

Comment: updated with key in salesorderdetails structure

Comment: I would suggest to make use of a JSON validator like: https://jsonlint.com/ or https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html.  I am not recommending either, I just grab one when I need it.

Comment: P.S. in Golang please use Tab instead of 4 spaces :)

Comment: how can we print OrderDetails, How to loop? for example to display salesid im using fmt.Printf("%+v\n ", temp[0].Salesorder.SalesId)

Comment: If you don't know how to use simple loops in Go, I recommend the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Order struct {
    SalesId     string `json:"sales_id"`
    Customer    string `json:"customer_name"`
    TotalPrice  string `json:"totalprice"`
}

type OrderDetails struct {
    SalesId   string `json:"sales_id"`
    ItemName  string `json:"item_name"`
    Qty       string `json:"qty"`
    Price     string `json:"price"`
}

type Temp struct {
    Salesorder Order                  `json:"Salesorder"`
    Salesorderdetails []OrderDetails  `json:"OrderDetails"`
}

func main() {
    jsonByteArray := []byte(`[{"Salesorder":{"sales_id":"SOO1","customer_name":"CUST1","totalprice":"200"}, "OrderDetails":[{"sales_id":"SOO1","item_name":"ITEM1","qty":"2","price":"100"},{"sales_id":"SOO2","item_name":"ITEM2","qty":"3","price":"200"}]}]`)

    var temp []Temp

    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &temp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //fmt.Printf("%+v\n", temp)

    // Printing all Orders with some details
    for _, order := range temp {
        fmt.Println("Customer:", order.Salesorder.Customer)

        for _, details := range order.Salesorderdetails {
            fmt.Printf("    ItemName: %s, Price: %s\n", details.ItemName, details.Price)
        }
    }
}
```

.. **OrderDetails** is an array now

Comment: how to print all the items in the structure

Comment: what items? You have only 2 main keys: Salesorder and OrderDetails. Second one is an array

Comment: how can we print OrderDetails, How to loop? for example to display salesid im using fmt.Printf("%+v\n ", temp[0].Salesorder.SalesId)

Comment: I've updated my code, run the new one. I print a customer(s) and order's ItemName with Price

Answer (score 1):

What you are tying to decode is not valid JSON.  This would be valid:

```
{
    "Salesorder": {
        "sales_id": "SOO1",
        "customer_name": "CUST1",
        "totalprice": "200"
    },
    "OrderDetails": {
        "sales_id": "SOO1",
        "item_name": "ITEM1",
        "qty": "2",
        "price": "100"
    }
}
```

But what you are giving is this:

```
{
    "Salesorder": {
        "sales_id": "SOO1",
        "customer_name": "CUST1",
        "totalprice": "200"
    },
    "OrderDetails": {
        "sales_id": "SOO1",
        "item_name": "ITEM1",
        "qty": "2",
        "price": "100"
    },
    {   // Things become invalid here
        "sales_id": "SOO2",
        "item_name": "ITEM2",
        "qty": "3",
        "price": "200"
    }
}
```

It looks like you are trying to give a list of objects, in which case you need to wrap those objects in square brackets `[]` or you will have to give the second `OrderDetails` object its own key.

Comment: how can i give in a valid json then?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are expecting for an output.  Does a single `SalesOrder` have multiple `OrderDetails`?

Comment: yes exactly, single SalesOrder have multiple OrderDetails

Comment: I think the other answer addresses that for you